# Why can't I change the value of a property of the styles object in React js , inside an event Listener after rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a jsx file :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
const styles = {
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "black"
};
ReactDom.render(
  <div>
    <h1 style={styles}>Good {wish}</h1>
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
document.querySelector("h1").addEventListener("click",function(){
  styles.color="salmon"; 
  console.log(styles);
});
```

I cannot change the styles object on click, it remains the same, "styles.color" is still "black".
Why can't I modify the styles object ?

Comment: Your component isn't changing when you update the "styles" because react doesn't know to rerender the component. To do so, you need to use the useState hook which means that when you update the state variable it triggers a rerender

Comment: Also I notice that you're trying to add event listeners to the dom elements themselves instead of using components which is strange because if you're using react you shouldn't have to touch the DOM at all, at the very least very rarely

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation is *almost always* the wrong approach in React.  Create a component, store the styles in state, update state in a click event.  Overall it looks like you should be starting with some introductory tutorials on React.

Comment: I wasn't doing any DOM manipulation, I wanted to know how that scenario would turn out to be , I was just curious, Anyways thank you guys for the suggestions.
But still when I log the styles object, styles.color is not updated , is there a reasoning for it?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be attempting to maniuplating the DOM when using react. It does that stuff for you!

Create a component

Mycomponent.jsx

```js
import {useState} from 'react';
function myComponent(wish){
const [styles,updateStyles] = useState();

function doSomething()
{
// Change styles here
updateStyles(/*Whatever you're doing to styles*/)
}

return(
<h1 style={styles} onClick={doSomething}>Good {wish}</h1>
)
}
export default myComponent;
```

and in your main component

main.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import MyComponent from './Mycomponent.jsx';
ReactDom.render(
  <div>
    <MyComponent wish={/*String here*/}/>
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
});
```

I highly recommend when you're starting a new project to use `create-react-app` because it does all this boilerplate stuff for you so you can get straight into coding in react instead of setting it up yourself. Also I would recommend to familiarize yourself with the official react documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this, but could you explain why the styles object is not updated. When I log it , why isn't the color property being changed? particularly after using the render function.

Comment: What react does is creates a 'virtual DOM' that it keeps track of and whenever component state updates (you changing the styles variable) it compares the new 'virtual DOM' to the actual DOM and reconciles the two so that the UI matches the application state. Since you changed application state in a way that react doesn't know about (attaching an event listener to the DOM element instead of through react) it doesn't know that it should update your component. Does that help?

Comment: also, you declared styles as a const in your example

Comment: Even if I did change the styles.color property outside the event listener, the styles object doesnt change.

Comment: But styles is an object which is stored in the heap right? And it is not a primitive , so I can assign a new value to one of its existing properties right?

Comment: Regardless, react doesn't know about the change, therefore it doesn't update the DOM